# Angular 2.0 Release candidate 1 upload issue

Tags: angular

I'm integration environment with django and python, when I try upload the file to the Django api rest I got the error: 415 unsupported media type.

Code below:

FORM TO UPLOAD BELOW:

THE FUNCTION TO CAPTURE THE EVENT:

```
fileChangeEvent(fileInput: any){
    this.filesToUpload = <Array<File>>fileInput.target.files;
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.uploadService.UploadFile(this._UploadUrl,[], this.filesToUpload).subscribe( res => {
        this.isLoading = false;

        if (res.status === 200) {;
            console.log("We have been posted file sucessfully");
            console.log("File: " + res.filename);
        } else {
            this.uploadMessage = true;
            console.log(res.status);
            this.myMessage=res.status;
            console.log("File: " + res.filename);
        }
    },(err) => {
        this.isLoading = false;
        this.uploadMessage = true;
        switch (err.status){
            case 404:
           this.myMessage="Backend component not found";
           this.myMessage+=err.message;
            console.log(err);
            break;
            case 403:
            this.myMessage="No access allowed by server";
            this.myMessage+=err.message;
            console.log(err);
            break;
            case 401:
            this.myMessage="No autorized";
            this.myMessage+=err.message;
            console.log(err);
            break;
            case 405:
            this.myMessage="Method don't allowed";
            this.myMessage+=err.message;
            console.log(err);
            break;
            case 408:
            this.myMessage="Request timeout";
            this.myMessage+=err.message;
            console.log(err);
            break;
            case 415:
            this.myMessage="Unsupported media type";
            this.myMessage+=err.message;
            console.log(err);
            break;
            case 500:
            this.myMessage="Internal server error";
            this.myMessage+=err.message;
            console.log(err);
            break;
            default:
            console.log(err);
            this.myMessage=err.message;
        }
    });

}
```

THE UPLOAD FUNCTION:

```
public UploadFile(URL:string, params: string[], req: any): Observable<any> {
    let body = JSON.stringify(req);
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=UTF-8');
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json, text/plain, text/html,  */*');
    console.log("body:");
    console.log(body);
    headers.append('Authorization', 'JWT ' + localStorage.getItem('token'));
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    console.log("options");
    console.log(options);
    return this.http.post(URL, body, options);

}
```

I tried with many different headers but no one of those are helping, I was wondering that maybe Angular2 release candidate 1 have an issue handling the upload files, can anybody confirm to me?

Comment: No idea; but you do know we are on Angular5 right...? At least get to 2 RTM

Comment: Sorry It's not an option here, project it's for very few time, and I know that directives was replaced with module declaration and that leads me to up re  several parts of the app and cannot be done in the given frame time. Thanks for your try.

Comment: POST request in angular 2 only supports String type. So for sending multipart data you have to use XHR.

Answer (score 1):

POST request in angular 2 only supports String type. So for sending multipart data you have to use XHR.

```
<input id="upfile" type="file" (change)=MyUploadFile($event.target.files) value="upload"/>

   public MyUploadFile(files: any) {
           console.log("Entered into uploadFile");
          for (let file of files) {
            console.log(file);
        }
        return new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{
            let formData: any = new FormData()
            let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
            for (let file of files) {
                formData.append("file", file)
            }

            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                    if (xhr.status === 200) {
                        //resolve(JSON.parse(xhr.response));
                        resolve(xhr.response);
                        console.log(xhr.response);
                    } else {
                        reject(xhr.response);
                        console.log(xhr.response);
                    }
                }
            }
            xhr.open("POST", this._UploadUrl, true)
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'JWT ' + localStorage.getItem('token'));
            xhr.send(formData)
        })
    }
```